# Why Does my MS Test Unit Test execute correctly in Debug Mode but Fails When in Normal run mode

Tags: vb.net, assert

I am using MS Test under VS2022 and have an issue with one of my unit tests.  I am using Assert.AreEqual to compare two string values, here is the test:

```
      <TestMethod()> Public Sub ShouldReturnaPIItemOfMWEqualTo1_ReadyForHttpSend()

      Try

           Dim da = New LVDataLoader
           Dim ana As New Analogue
           Dim anas As New Analogues
           Dim inp As New LVItem
           Dim expected As String = "0.0012"
           Dim result As String = ""

           inp.TransformerId = "1"
           inp.InstrumentId = "1"
           inp.SubjectAssetId = "1"
           inp.SubjectAssetName = "L1 section of Feeder: 1"
           inp.EngUnit = "MW L1"
           inp.Value = "1201.1999499999999"

           result = da.GetPIItem(inp).Value.ToString

           Assert.AreEqual(expected, result)
      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      End Try

 End Sub
```

and here is the Method being called from the LVDataLoader instance:

```
      Public Function GetPIItem(ByVal lvItem As LVItem) As PIItem

      Dim piitem As New PIItem
      Dim licArea As String
      Dim tagName As String
      Dim typeCode As String
      Dim ana As New Analogue
      Dim clnEngUnit As String

      Try

           'First determine the license area for this item we do so by looking up the transformer id in the substation list
           licArea = Right(GetSubstation(lvItem.TransformerId).LicenceArea, 1)

           'Determine the typecode for the engineering unit in question
           'by comparing the engineering unit passed to the engineering unit property
           'in the list of digitals.
           If IsDigital(lvItem.EngUnit, Digitals) Then
                typeCode = _digitalTypeCode
           Else
                typeCode = _analogueTypeCode
           End If

           'Now build the tag name
           clnEngUnit = mutl.GetNthElement(lvItem.EngUnit, " ", 1)
           tagName = licArea & "~" & _voltage & "~" &
                          lvItem.TransformerId & "~" &
                          lvItem.InstrumentId & "-" & lvItem.SubjectAssetId & "~" &
                          lvItem.SubjectAssetName & "~" &
                          lvItem.EngUnit & "~" & typeCode

           piitem.TagAttribute = _tagAttribute
           piitem.TagRef = tagName
           piitem.TagName = tagName
           piitem.TimeStamp = lvItem.Time
           piitem.Quality = "192"
           piitem.Value = Math.Round(ana.Convert(clnEngUnit, lvItem.Value, _analogues), 5)
           piitem.ServerName = _destDatabase

           Return piitem
      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      End Try

 End Function
```

The assertion is pretty straightforward (or so I thought), I appreciate that were I comparing two objects that the above assertion would fail, however I thought that since these are native .NET datatypes that I should be able to use without resorting to overriding Equals, (how would you override Equals anyway for a native .net datatype?).  Things get even  stranger though.  If I execute the test in Debug mode it executes as expected, however if I run the test normally it fails... What is going on here?

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: does your assertion say what the actual result is? I'd guess there's some difference in the rounding (either of the input or the results)

Comment: Note that you can use assert directly on doubles, there is an argument which will let you specify the precision below which you don't care about differences. @TZHX If it's being run in the test explorer, it will display both expected and actual values.